# compiler error c1001 in generic class

Tags: generics, compiler-errors, c++-cli

In my class

```
generic <class T>  
public ref class CFifo
{
public:
  enum class EnumResult
  { ... }

  EnumResult AddData (int i_iStart, int i_iLength, array<T>^ i_aData);
  ...
}
```

I get a compiler crash ("c/c++ optimizing compiler has stopped working") with error c1001, and the advice to simplify my class. The failure occurs at the `return` line in the .cpp:

```
generic <class T>
CFifo<T>::EnumResult CFifo<T>::AddData (int       i_iStart,
                                        int       i_iLength,
                                        array<T>^ i_aData)
{
...
  return CResult<EnumResult>::TraceMsg (ms_tracesource, TraceEventType::Error, EnumResult::Error_MutexTimeout, __FUNCTION__"()", "timeout at receiving mutex.");
```

The class `CResult` is another generic class:

```
generic <class TResult> where TResult : value class  // value class constraint is not necessary
public ref class CResult abstract sealed
```

I am using the same line `CResult<EnumResult>::TraceMsg` in other classes without problems.

I can create and use variables of `EnumResult` without errors, so I think that passing this type to the generic class `CResult` should work, too.

Can anyone explain why the compiler crashes and how to fix it if possible? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Failure found:

It was the `value class` constraint in `generic <class TResult> ref class CResult`.
As soon as I removed it, the compiler crash was gone. Weird.

I had to modify my code in `CResult` though:
from

```
return static_cast<TResult>(iResult);
```

to

```
return static_cast<TResult>(System::Enum::ToObject (TResult::typeid, iResult));
```

because I am no longer able to cast from `int` to `TResult` directly, which was possible before due to the `value class` constraint.